# javascript: use getElementByID to populate multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

is there a way to write the same thing clientside using javascript to multiple divs or multiple spots on a page?

I have a php script outputting rows from a database.  To edit the contents, I would like to insert a checkbox before each row as with the iphone edit contacts and to do it quickly, I'm trying to use javascript to populate a div with a checkbox before each row using getElemenByID.

One problem is you cannot have more than one div of the same name on a page so I can't write once and have it populate multiple divs of the same name.  If I give divs different names than I have to write multiple times which is not appealing especially as the number of rows may vary.

As a related question would checkboxes inserted using javascript even work?

Here is non working code:

js

```
function edit() }
var box = '<input type="checkbox name=num[]>';
var target = "checkbox";
document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = box;
return;
}//end function
```

html (generated by PHP from dbase)

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post">
<a href="javascript:void" onclick="edit()";>edit</a>
<div id="checkbox"></div>Row1 contents<br>
<div id="checkbox"></div>Row2 contents<br>
<form type = "submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

Does anyone know a way to do this ie make boxes appear that can then be selected for submission?

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Should be generated using PHP instead, but...

### HTML

I'm guessing that you want to use a span element (not a div) for your checkbox placeholder, otherwise you'd have a checkbox on one line, and then "Row1 contents" *below* the checkbox, versus having the checkbox next to the text.

```
[X]
Row 1 Contents
```

versus (span)

```
[X] Row 1 Contents
```

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post" name="frmRows" id="frmRows">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="edit()">edit</a>
    <span class="checkbox"></span>Row1 contents<br>
    <span class="checkbox"></span>Row2 contents<br>
    <input type = "submit" value="Edit">
</form>
```

### JavaScript

It's not recommended to use .innerHTML in JavaScript unless absolutely necessary (not supported in all browsers, and there are better ways to accomplish the same task.)

```
function edit() {
    var newCb;
    var i;
    var checkboxList = document.getElementsByClassName( 'checkbox' );

    for ( i = 0; i < checkboxList.length; i++ ) {

        newCb = document.createElement( 'input' ); // Create a new input element

        newCb.setAttribute( 'type', 'checkbox' ); // Set attributes for new element
        newCb.setAttribute( 'value', 'SomeValueHere' );
        newCb.setAttribute( 'name', 'checkboxName' );
        newCb.setAttribute( 'id', 'checkbox-' + i );

        checkboxList[i].appendChild( newCB ); // Add checkbox to span.checkbox
    }
}
```

Comment: Really (in this case) this should all be generated server-side with PHP, not via JavaScript. That way you could write a PHP loop to generate all of the HTML and row values and send plain HTML to the client. If you post a new question on how to generate the form using PHP, I'd be glad to help.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct answer as it is a good way to populate the divs/spans.  However, I can't get the html form to recognize the values inserted by the javascript (the second part of my question).  Do values inserted in divs through getElementById client-side get recognized in html forms...or not?

Comment: Keep in mind that .setAttribute( 'value', 'SomeValueHere') on a checkbox won't actually display a value on the page; that is the value passed to the server-side when the form is submitted. Are you talking about the text that would display next to the checkbox, or the value of the checkbox once it hits the server?

Comment: Ideally, I would like it to do both.  Change text on page in response to user checking box so user sees what will be submitted.  Then when users clicks submit form, it sends the value the user sees to server.

Answer (score 1):

The ID attribute must be unique on each page. You could use the class attribute like this:

```
<div class="checkbox"></div>Row1 contents<br>
<div class="checkbox"></div>Row2 contents<br>
```

and then you can use

```
var check = getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
for (var i=0; i< check.length; i++) {
    check[i].innerHTML = box;
}
```

But... this [will not work in IE < 9](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname). If you are using a framework like jQuery they already implemented a workaround for this but with pure JS you have to implement this yourself.

**jQuery example**

HTML

```
<div class="checkbox"></div>Row1 contents<br>
<div class="checkbox"></div>Row2 contents<br>
```

JS

```
var box = '<input type="checkbox" name="num[]" />';
$(".checkbox").html(box);
```

Comment: While there is no `document.getElementsById` polyfill for IE, there are enough functions that are /almost/ a drop in replacement.  Don't need to pull in jQuery just for that.

Answer (score 1):

## The HTML

The first thing to do is to update the generated HTML. In HTML element `id` attributes should be unique just like field names inside a form. To classify multiple elements as similar you should use the `class` attribute.

Here is an example of how you could structure the HTML.

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post">
<a href="javascript:void" onclick="edit">edit</a>
<div id="row1Identifier" class="editCheckbox"></div>Row1 contents</br>
<div id="row2Identifier" class="editCheckbox"><?div>Row2 contents</br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

## The javascript

Using `document.getElementsByClassName` will return a list of elements with the matching class.

```
​function edit () {
    // set up the variables used in this function
    var checkboxDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('editCheckbox'),
        i,
        loopDiv;
    // make the change to each div
    for (i = 0; i < checkboxDivs.length; i += 1) {
        loopDiv = checkboxDivs[i];
        loopDiv.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="' + loopDiv.id + '">';
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could do it with a single line (using jQuery, for exemplo), you would actually be running a loop through all the divs (that's the only way to change something in various elements: change it in each one).

So you can do this with pure JavaScript using a loop to run the modifications in all the divs, getting them by id (the faster way):

```
for(var i = 0; i < numberOfDivs; i++){
  document.getElementById("myElement" + i).innerHTML = box; //concatenating i to a base id
}
```

You could also use another slower techniques to get elements by tag name or class, or even use a lib such as jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery:

```
function edit() {
// box = '<input type="checkbox name=num[]>'; 
var target = "checkbox"; 
$(".cb").html(box);
return; 
}//end function 

<form action="edit.php" method="post"> 
<a href="#" onclick="edit();"> edit</a> 
<div class="cb" id="checkbox">aa</div>Row1 contents<br> 
<div class="cb" id="checkbox">bb</div>Row2 contents<br> 
</form>
```